# Accessing Open Activities fields linked to a Case in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

Using email to case I am able to save email body in the Open activities related section of the case. 
I want to write a query / way in case trigger to fetch the email body attached to a activity into a string so that I can parse it to get certain values.

I am using Querying sObject Relationships but not able to get anywhere...
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using email-to-case the email's body should be embedded into Case already?

Try one of these 2 queries (of course provide an id that will work for you)

```
select Id, FromAddress, HtmlBody, Incoming, Subject, TextBody, ToAddress 
FROM EmailMessage
WHERE ParentId = '500D000000KUXYP'

SELECT Id, Subject, (SELECT TextBody FROM EmailMessages)
FROM Case 
WHERE Id = '500D000000KUXYP'
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for replying so late. As the core of my question was to parse the incoming email on the salesforce. I discontinued the email to case approach and used the Inbound Email handler provided buy the Salesforce and written my own APEX class by extending the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for replying so late.
As the core of my question was to parse the incoming email on the salesforce. I discontinued the email to case approach and used the Inbound Email handler provided buy the Salesforce and written my own APEX class by extending the handler.

In the same class, I accessed the case object and updated the fields required.